# Would a question about food digestion be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about the mechanics of digesting food.  Would that be on topic here?  I'm thinking no, am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not unless there's some subtle or tenuous connection to the cooking process that I'm not anticipating.

We do seem to have a [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) site on the network now; if your question is at a reasonably technical research-ish level then you could try asking there, although I suspect, like most of the other science sites, that it'd get closed if it's deemed overly simplistic or if you're looking for somebody to break a complex subject down into layman's terms.

Comment: The only tenuous connection to cooking is that I'm trying to figure out how small to chop food for an eater with few/no teeth from a perspective of maximizing digestion rather than from the avoiding choking perspective.  I think that's a too-tenuous connection.  Just wanted to check.

Comment: @justkt: I assume we're talking about a baby? What about [parenting.se]?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct, that would be a medical question.